# How to compare primitives with Java Generics?

Tags: java, generics

I am learning java Generics. I would like to compare primitives using unbounded Generics.I have the following code,

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T x, T y) {
    return x > y ? x : y;
}
```

but it won't compile. The error is:

```
The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) T
```

Comment: Comparable allows you to use the compareTo method. It does not override the comparison operators.

Comment: I missed the compareTo call. Is there a way to overload the operator like in C++?

Comment: No. Java does not allow operator overriding nor overloading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare two `Comparable` objects, you *must* use `compareTo`, here `x.compareTo(y)`.  Your method can be written

```
return x.compareTo(y) > 0 ? x : y;
```

Comment: I figured this out, I can't believe I missed this!